# TypeError: iteration over a 0-d array, using numpy and pydicom

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, tkinter, pydicom

I am trying to create a simple DICOM viewer, in which I plot the image using matplotlib and I want to show that same plot(which is a DICOM image) in tkinter, but when I run the code I get this error. please help. The error occurs when I try to plot a, but I believe it has something to do wuth the way I declared the values of x, y, and p

```
import pydicom
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import 
FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from tkinter import *
from pydicom.data import get_testdata_files

filename = get_testdata_files('000000.dcm')
dataset = pydicom.dcmread('000000.dcm')
data = dataset.pixel_array

class mclass:
  def __init__(self, window):
    self.window = window
    self.button=Button(window,text="check",command=self.plot)
    self.button.pack()

  def plot (self):
      if 'PixelData' in dataset:
          rows = int(dataset.Rows)
          cols = int(dataset.Columns)
      y=np.array(rows)
      x=np.array(cols)
      p=np.array(data)
      fig = Figure(figsize=(6,6))
      a = fig.add_subplot(111)
      a.plot(p, range(2+max(y)))

      canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=self.window)
      canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
      canvas.draw()

window = Tk()
start = mclass (window)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You don't indicate where the error occurs.  It's a good idea to add some `print(x.shape)` statements where you suspect array dimension problems.  Keeping track of dimensions is crucial when working with `numpy`.

Comment: sorry about that, the error appears when I am trying to plot a. I believe it has something to do with the way I declared the values of y, x and p

Comment: What is the exact error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the look of it your error lies here :

```
y=np.array(rows)
...
a.plot(p, range(2+max(y)))
```

You ask for the `max(y)`, but the `ds.Rows` and `ds.Columns` you use to instantiate `x` and `y` are scalar values (and to be doubly sure you use `int(ds.Rows)`). This means that both `x` and `y` will be a 0-dimensional array and this would explain the thrown error, presumably on `max(y)`. Try :

```
if 'PixelData' in dataset:
      rows = int(dataset.Rows)
      cols = int(dataset.Columns)
  y=rows
  x=cols
  p=np.array(data)
  fig = Figure(figsize=(6,6))
  a = fig.add_subplot(111)
  a.plot(p, range(2+y))
```